# Displaying Search results in a random order

Tags: magento-1.9, search, random

I need to display the products on the search results page in a random order. Since there is no official explanation on how to do this, I tried to edit the `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext` module, but I could't figure out where to add a `ORDER BY RAND()` in the `prepareResults()` function. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordering actually happens in `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext/Collection.php` You can change `::setOrder()` to look like this in order to **always** sort randomly – regardless of the sort attribute selected by the user:

```
public function setOrder($attribute, $dir = 'desc')
{
    /* ORIGINAL CODE
    if ($attribute == 'relevance') {
        $this->getSelect()->order("relevance {$dir}");
    } else {
        parent::setOrder($attribute, $dir);
    }
    */

    // RANDOM SORT INSTEAD
    $this->getSelect()->getAdapter()->orderRand($this->getSelect());

    return $this;
}
```

Bear in mind that you're changing a core file so for real world code you should consider creating a custom module. You can e.g. listen to the `catalog_block_product_list_collection` event and modify the collection sort in an observer if applicable.